# Set path for favicon in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to make my favicon.ico accessible as `http://domain/favicon.ico` (same for apple-touch-icon.png) but can't manage to do that.
I put favicon in my root theme folder but it is not accessible form there.

What I'm doing wrong? and how to do that properly?

Thanks!

Comment: On theme settings page, try this:
/favicon.ico in the provided text box

Answer (score 0):

Apache? Check your .htaccess file. Refer to these pages:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1588820

https://www.drupal.org/project/favicon